# Error when opening some Outlook MailItems with GetItemFromID using EntryID from Outlook Spy

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi, mailitem

When I Use OutlookSpy to get the EntryIDs from MailItems in a particular folder and supply them to the following code:

```
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

try
{
  object obj = mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(sEntryID);
  if (obj is Outlook.MailItem)
  {
    var getItem = (Outlook.MailItem)mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(sEntryID);
    getItem.Display();
  }
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
  Global.Common.LogError("Error accessing MailItem", Ex, "EntryID " + sEntryID + " not found in " + sFolder, "Warning");
}
```

I get unknown messaging errors for some EntryID values and successful display of the messages in Outlook with others. Can anyone suggest what attributes the MailItems might have which will affect whether I can display them successfully using GetItemFromID or any other method of displaying all messages by EntryID reliably?

Comment: What error exactly do you get in the code? Error message?

Comment: Please let me know whether specifying the second parameter explicitly helps or not.

Answer (score 1):

Was the message store where the message resides touched in the active Outlook session? The way MAPI providers work, when a provider is loaded by MAPI, it registers the set of entry id guids (bytes 5-20 in the entry id) that it will handle. If the particular PST store has not been touched in the current session, MAPI does not know anything about its entry ids.

You can either access all the stores in the current session first (to make sure MAPI knows about their entry ids) or use the store entry id (second parameter, optional) when calling GetItemFromId - this way Outlook will open the store first, then ask the store to open the item. You can also call Namespace.AddStore / AddStoreEx to load the given PST file if it is not already in the current profile.

You might also want to log the exception details (Ex.Message) in your exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the respondents - this explains why sometimes particular messages would open and sometimes they would not. By getting the StoreId using the following code:

```
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
                    Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                    Object oStoreID = Common.GetFolder(myApp, sFolder).StoreID;
                    try
                    {
                        object obj = mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(sEntryID,oStoreID);
                        if (obj is Outlook.MailItem)
                        {
                            Outlook.MailItem getItem = (Outlook.MailItem)mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(sEntryID,oStoreID);
                            getItem.Display();
                        }
                    }
```

Where

```
       public static Outlook.Folder GetFolder(Outlook.Application App, string folderPath)
    {
        Outlook.Folder folder;
        string backslash = @"\";
        try
        {
            if (folderPath.StartsWith(@"\\"))
            {
                folderPath = folderPath.Remove(0, 2);
            }
            String[] folders =
                folderPath.Split(backslash.ToCharArray());
            folder =
                App.Session.Folders[folders[0]]
                as Outlook.Folder;
            if (folder != null)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= folders.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                {
                    Outlook.Folders subFolders = folder.Folders;
                    folder = subFolders[folders[i]]
                        as Outlook.Folder;
                    if (folder == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return folder;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

All MailItems now display in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just throw this in here for posterity-- Outlook 2002 requires that the entry ID supplied to GetItemFromID use upper-case hex characters.